# .split is not a function

Tags: javascript

Вроде гуглил и ошибка такая возникает когда передается не String. Здесь вроде всё ок, но почему то ошибка. Подскажиет плиз.

```
var datem = document.getElementsByClassName('starttime');
for (var i = 0; i < datem.length; i++) {
alert(i); // 0
alert( datem[i].textContent); // 12.00 - 14.00
alert (typeof datem[i].textContent); //string
var datemn = datem[i].split('-');
alert (datemn);
}
```

Comment: Подобная ситуация и ответ на enSO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145946/what-is-causing-the-error-string-split-is-not-a-function

Comment: `split` не применима к обьектам. Нужна строка слева. А `datem[i]` - обьект.

Comment: вы проверяете на тип `datem[i].textContent`, а пытаетесь применить `split` на  `datem[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без комментариев:

```js
var datem = document.getElementsByClassName('starttime');
for (var i = 0; i < datem.length; i++) {

console.log( datem[i].textContent);
var datemn = datem[i].textContent.split('-');
console.log( datemn);
}
```

```html
<span class="starttime">12.00 - 14.00</span>
```

Хотя не понятно зачем вам тут цикл...

Comment: Спасибо. Цикл понадобится в дальнейшем, елементов с классом starttime несколько.

Comment: @СлаваПавлов если у вас новый вопрос на эту тему, отредактируйте и добавьте код в основной вопрос, а то так ничего не понятно )

Comment: нет вопросов больше нет просто хотел скинуть результат, но я насколько понял в комментариях код куском не скинуть, можно только строки.